# Styling php? Trying to remove the styling put in place from nav bar, for php live-search links

Tags: php, css, stylesheet, livesearch

I am trying to create a live search bar that generates links, which works fine with PHP and javascript. However, the `<a href=''>` links that are presented from the PHP file are pre-styled for my navigation bar (which the search bar is embedded in).

I want to remove all styling on the links produced from the live-search bar. please help! :)

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<div class=bricken><a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a></div>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><div class=bricken><a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a></div>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

The quotes in this file seems to prevent me from styling the `<a>` properly. :(

This is what the css looks like for the `<a>`:

```css
#header nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 35px;
    font-weight: 200;
}

#header nav a {
    color: #5c6c8f;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-left: 60px;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #5c6c8f;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    font-family: georgia;
    background-color: whitesmoke;

}

#header nav a:hover {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

please let me know what im doing wrong. thanks!

EDIT:

I've fixed the styling issue, now I need the search results to not push the search bar up. You can see the here:

www.trifoldbooks.com

Type "R" into the search bar.

Comment: Just comment out the styles in the stylesheet controlling the links.

Comment: I need those styles for the nav bar though

Comment: why not adding extra class to those link and override  those link style using your css? for example  `$hint="<div class=bricken new_class><a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a></div>";`